# Python speech recognition recorder.listen(audio) stops after a few seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, audio-recording

I was working with python speech recognition and it works well, but can't get my head around this.
Issue:

1. when working with an audio file
2. when using *recorder*.listen(audio)
3. for some reason, it only listens for a couple of seconds and then stops
4. so it only listens to a part of the audio file and then ignores the rest

This is the simplified code I'm running with the exact same issue:

```
import os
import speech_recognition as sr

recog = sr.Recognizer()
audioFile = sr.AudioFile('C:\\Users\ilieg\OneDrive\Documents\Sound recordings\male.wav')
transcript = ""

with audioFile as source:
    audio = recog.listen(source)

    transcript = transcript + " " + recog.recognize_google(audio)
print(transcript)
```

If you need a sample of the audio file...I got it from here, just for testing purposes: (I used the first audio file)

http://www.signalogic.com/index.pl?page=codec_samples

Example:
The output of the following [(click for audio file)](http://www.signalogic.com/melp/EngSamples/Orig/male.wav) audio file is:
**what if somebody decides to break it be careful that you keep adequate coverage but look for places to save money baby it's taking longer to get things squared away than the bankers expected during the wife or ones company may win her tax hated retirement income to boost is helpful to saving Rags are hers Lee tossed on the two naked bones**

Comment: I can't reproduce, it works fine on my machine (Mac OS X) with Python3. By the way, what do you use `step` for?

Comment: sorry, **step** isn't used for anything, was just debugging, I'll remove it.

Comment: What output do you get if you use this as input file? http://www.signalogic.com/melp/EngSamples/Orig/male.wav

Comment: The code should run on any machine that has **python**, *pyaudio* and *speechrecognition* libraries. 
My problem is that whenever I run it to listen/record (whether you use `recognizer.listen()` or `@recognizer.record(audio)`) to an audio file, it runs for a couple of seconds and then it just stops for no reason and prints only the first 20 seconds of the audio usually. Not sure if I'm an outlier, or someone else had this problem and managed to fix it ar there's something that I'm missing.
P.S. `recognizer.record(audio,duration=x)`, where `x` is more than 20 seconds, doesn't work either :D

Comment: The input wav file I linked above is 51s and all of it is transcribed by your code snippet. And the transcription process takes ~18s.

Comment: the output to that particular audio file is:
*what if somebody decides to break it be careful that you keep adequate coverage but look for places to save money baby it's taking longer to get things squared away than the bankers expected during the wife or ones company may win her tax hated retirement income to boost is helpful to saving Rags are hers Lee tossed on the two naked bones*
which is about the first 22 seconds of the 52s audio file :(

Comment: Again, I can't reproduce it, sorry, I get the all transcription. Can you try to print some properties of the recognizer? In particular `energy_threshold` and `pause_threshold`.

Comment: OK. I'll look into that and maybe post them later. Thank a lot for the help anyways :). Hopefully, there are more people that could contribute to this in the future.

Comment: It's as easy as doing `print(recog.energy_threshold)` and `print(recog.pause_threshold)`. The more information you put in the question the more people will jump in to help ;-)